# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null.`

I want to redirect to another page if checked at least one check box. What is it I missed?

```
function check(){

 for(var i = 0;i < 3;i++){
    var x = document.getElementById("c" + String(i)).checked;

    if (x == true){
        alert('select');
        window.location = "#";
    }
    else {
        alert('not select');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which means there is no element with the said id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have 3 checkboxes with id "c0", "c1" and "c2"?
Some of these are not present on your page!

Make sure that you call your function on document ready event:
The example using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   check();
});
```

Comment: Where did you see the page?